# Can I save an ImageData or Image into a new file with löve2d in lua?

Tags: image, lua, love2d, moonscript

I need to know if it's possible to save an "*ImageData*" (or something like that) into a new file in **Lua** with **Löve2D**, and how ?
If I can't, how can I do that ?

thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Love2D ImagaData objects can be encoded via the "[Encode](https://love2d.org/wiki/ImageData:encode)" function, in Love 0.10.0

```
img:encode(type, filename)
```

in 0.8.0 and later, Type was not required.

Comment: @AlexandreCombeau It is good practice to accept answers that solved your problem.